# "time 2002ms" in ping response

Tags: networking

I would like to know, in this ping reply

```
64 bytes from xxxxxxxx: icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=51.1 ms
64 bytes from xxxxxxxx: icmp_req=2 ttl=51 time=50.1 ms
64 bytes from xxxxxxxx: icmp_req=3 ttl=51 time=50.6 ms

--- xxxxxxx ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 50.112/50.614/51.101/0.480 ms
```

what is "time 2002ms"? 
Why is it usually omitted? I have never seen it in other ping tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the time from the first sent ping packet to the last sent ping packet. In your example, from the first to the third sent packet (two one second intervals separating them)

The reason it's often omitted is that it's not usually very relevant information for a user, since the relevant information usually is how many packets were sent and received, and what the round trip was.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, how can I get this information? Have I to indicate a command in the ECHO REQUEST?

Comment: @user1290378 That information has nothing to do with the network. Just save the current time in the variables "a" and "b" when you send the first ECHO REQUEST, then update the variable "b" every time you send a new ECHO REQUEST. When you're done, just display the time between "b" and "a".